# how does the expose port work in buildah

Tags: linux, networking, docker

I have windows 8.1 OS with vmware workstation installed running the rhel8 server as guest OS. In the rhel8 server i am building a image from an already existing tomcat container as below

```
[root@rhelser8 ~]# buildah from docker.io/library/tomcat
Getting image source signatures
...
Writing manifest to image destination
Storing signatures
tomcat-working-container
```

With the above step as indicated in the documentation i am getting the 'tomcat-working-container' which i am trying to run as below

```
[root@rhelser8 ~]# buildah run tomcat-working-container catalina.sh run
```

So, i am able to start the tomcat container and access it from another terminal of my host rhelser8 as below

```
[root@rhelser8 ~]# curl http://localhost:8080/
[root@rhelser8 ~]# curl http://IP_address:8080/
```

But when i access the second url from my Windows host machine i am unable to access the tomcat default page.

But if i am running the container image using podman using the below command

```
[root@rhelser8 ~]# podman run -it -d -p 8888:8080 container_image
```

i am able to access the second url from my Windows host machine and from rhel8 host, i.e. url - http://IP_address:8080/

what i am trying to understand is that when using buildah i am able to access the page from rhel8 host using its hostip but not from the windows host

But if am using podman and publishing the port using -p i am able to access the page from rhel8 host as well as from the windows host

I need to understand this behaviour.

Comment: Are you sure you can connect from the windows host to http://IP_address:8080/ (not port 8888). Also whar kind of network do you use with the VM (NAT, bridged, ...).